# Not getting option for biometric face authentication

Tags: face-recognition, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt, biometricmanager

I am using biometric authentication for getting into the app, but the problem is I am not getting option for face-authentication.
This is the gradle dependency
implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric-ktx:1.2.0-alpha05"
This is the code I am using, firstly checking if authentication is possible then using it

````
 if (CommonMethods.isBiometricReady(requireActivity())) {
            binding.tvBioMetric.visible()
        }
fun isBiometricReady(context: Context) =
            hasBiometricCapability(context) == BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS

        private fun hasBiometricCapability(context: Context): Int {
            val biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(context)
            return biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_WEAK)
        }

private fun initBiometricPrompt(
        activity: AppCompatActivity
    ): BiometricPrompt {

        val executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(activity)

        val callback = object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {

            override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
                super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthenticationError: ")
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                Log.w(TAG, "Authentication failed for an unknown reason")
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                verified()
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthenticationSucceeded: ${result.cryptoObject}")
            }
        }

        // 3
        return BiometricPrompt(activity, executor, callback)
    }


  fun setBiometricPromptInfo(
            title: String,
            subtitle: String,
            description: String,
            allowDeviceCredential: Boolean
        ): BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo {
            val builder = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle(title)
                .setSubtitle(subtitle)
                .setDescription(description)

            // Use Device Credentials if allowed, otherwise show Cancel Button
            builder.apply {
                if (allowDeviceCredential) setAllowedAuthenticators(BIOMETRIC_WEAK)
                else setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
            }

            return builder.build()
        } ```

on click of tvBiometric
```initBiometricPrompt(requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).authenticate(
                        setBiometricPromptInfo("Authentications", "", "", false)
                    )```

The scenario is I am not getting face authentication option at all, if both the fingerprint and face authentication is set on device, the function has Biometric returns true and shows option only for fingerprint authentication
Now if I disable fingerprint but face id is enabled then has biometric returns false, the issue is **face authentication doesn't work at all**
Please help how to resolve it.
I checked using this code also
````

````
    val biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(requireContext())
    when (biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK or BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG)) {
        BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS ->
            ("Biometric authentication is available").showToast(requireContext())

        BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE ->
            ("This device doesn't support biometric authentication").showToast(requireContext())

        BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE ->
            ("Biometric authentication is currently unavailable").showToast(requireContext())

       BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED ->
            ("No biometric credentials are enrolled").showToast(requireContext())
    } ```
````

it returns BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED even if face id is enrolled
I have also tried Biometric_Strong but this also doesn't work
I tested on device Xiaomi android version 12